# Centring emblem with site title Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, header, inline

I am trying to inline a sports emblem centred with the site title using Twenty Eleven on Wordpress, however I am unable to get this to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Here is the relevant code:

```
 <header id="branding" role="banner">    
     <hgroup> 
          <h1 id="site-title">
               <img src="http://aberdeenshirecc.org.uk/phpHrX1SaAM.jpg"style="width:84px;height:100px;     display:inline; vertical-align:center; img margin-top:200px; ">
               <span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' )    ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span>
          </h1>
```

Unfortunately was unable to add divs to the child theme, so had to use the style= in the actual img tag.

Comment: Since it is a CSS related issue, I advice to add CSS code, and also CSS tag to get better help from SO.

Comment: I tired that with inline:centre but that didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I dont have solution for you, I am only giving advice on better way of asking question on SO.

Comment: Fair enough, although had to use the style= in the img tag as the Divs were not getting picked up from Wordpress using the child theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.. or if you really wish to do it by the img's CSS use `display: block;` and auto margin. In your case:

```
<img src="http://aberdeenshirecc.org.uk/phpHrX1SaAM.jpg" style="width:84px; height:100px; display:block; margin: 200px auto 0;">
```